# how to fetch '/' separated node/tag name from a given xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

i want to fetch '/' separated node name from a given xml such that only node/tag name are getting fetched instead of node/tag value from a given xml.

Suppose if i have below xml :

```xml
<ns:manageWorkItemRequest>
    <ns:wiFocus>
        <act:orderDate>2020-03-16T10:30:56.000Z</act:orderDate>
        <act:orderItem>
            <agr:instance>
                <spec1:customerServiceIdentifier>ETHA15302121</spec1:customerServiceIdentifier>
                <spec1:instanceCharacteristic>
                    <spec1:action>
                        <spec1:code>Modify</spec1:code>
                    </spec1:action>
                    <spec1:instanceIdentifier>
                        <spec1:value>OS014-AHEFV5T9</spec1:value>
                </spec1:instanceIdentifier>
             </agr:instance>
        </act:orderItem>
        <act:orderVersion>1</act:orderVersion>
    </ns:wiFocus>
    <ns:wiAction>Create</ns:wiAction>
    <ns:wiVersion>1</ns:wiVersion>
</ns:manageWorkItemRequest>
```

I want result as :

> ns:manageWorkItemRequest/ns:wiFocus/act:orderItem/agr:instance/spec1:customerServiceIdentifier/ETHA15302121

actually the requirement is if i get this "ETHA15302121" value in above xml then i should show the path i.e. where exactly in xml that value is in '/' separated format.

Comment: I don't see this happening. XQuery support in SQL Server is a partial implementation of v1. No custom functions, not even support for `name()` (only `local-name()`, which won't include namespaces). T-SQL is Turing-complete, so technically it's possible to do it, but it would be so hard/inefficient that you're almost certainly better off shifting this to client code (or using a CLR function if it absolutely must happen on the DB side).

Comment: The XML is not well-formed. XML namespaces declarations are missing.

Comment: thanks @JeroenMostert  for providing view point for this ill discuss it with my team regarding the requirements.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right, that SQL-Server is not built for this and also with your assumption, that this can be done in T-SQL. I've placed an approach... :-)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky My answer might be interesting for you :-)

Comment: @Shnugo: that's not as bad as I expected -- still nothing I'd unleash on production if there was any way of doing it client-side instead, but props for the solution regardless.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've just added a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61886650/5089204) with an enhanced approach covering namespaces, mutli-text elements and attributes. Might be interesting for you...

Comment: @robinsaxena,  I've just added a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61886650/5089204) with an enhanced approach covering namespaces, mutli-text elements and attributes. Might be interesting for you...

Answer (score 2):

Your XML was not well-formed (missing closing tag in the middle and missing namespace declarations.

After adding the missing parts it looks as so and you might try something along this route (warning: this won't be fast...):

Your XML

```sql
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root xmlns:ns="dummy1" xmlns:act="dummy2" xmlns:agr="dummy3" xmlns:spec1="dummy4">
  <ns:manageWorkItemRequest>
    <ns:wiFocus>
      <act:orderDate>2020-03-16T10:30:56.000Z</act:orderDate>
      <act:orderItem>
        <agr:instance>
          <spec1:customerServiceIdentifier>ETHA15302121</spec1:customerServiceIdentifier>
          <spec1:instanceCharacteristic>
            <spec1:action>
              <spec1:code>Modify</spec1:code>
            </spec1:action>
            <spec1:instanceIdentifier>
              <spec1:value>OS014-AHEFV5T9</spec1:value>
            </spec1:instanceIdentifier>
          </spec1:instanceCharacteristic>
        </agr:instance>
      </act:orderItem>
      <act:orderVersion>1</act:orderVersion>
    </ns:wiFocus>
    <ns:wiAction>Create</ns:wiAction>
    <ns:wiVersion>1</ns:wiVersion>
  </ns:manageWorkItemRequest>
</root>';
```

--the query

```sql
WITH AllNamespaces As
(
    SELECT  CONCAT('ns',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (B.namespaceUri))) Prefix
           ,B.namespaceUri
    FROM @xml.nodes('//*') A(nd)
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES(A.nd.value('namespace-uri(.)','nvarchar(max)')))B(namespaceUri)
    WHERE LEN(B.namespaceUri)>0
    GROUP BY B.namespaceUri
)
,recCte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS NestLevel
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.nd) AS ElementPosition
          ,CAST(REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.nd),5),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(900)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS SortString
          ,CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),'[',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')) ORDER BY A.nd),']') AS FullName
          ,CAST(CONCAT('/',ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),'[',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')) ORDER BY A.nd),']') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS XPath
          ,A.nd.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
          ,A.nd.query('./*') NextFragment
    FROM @xml.nodes('/*') A(nd)
    LEFT JOIN AllNamespaces ns ON ns.namespaceUri=A.nd.value('namespace-uri(.)','nvarchar(max)') 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.NestLevel+1
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.nd)  
          ,CAST(CONCAT(r.SortString,REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.nd),5),' ','0')) AS VARCHAR(900)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
          ,CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),'[',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')) ORDER BY A.nd),']') AS FullName
          ,CONCAT(r.XPath,'/',ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)'),'[',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(ns.Prefix+':',A.nd.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')) ORDER BY A.nd),']') AS FullName
          ,A.nd.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
          ,A.nd.query('./*') NextFragment
    FROM recCte r
    CROSS APPLY NextFragment.nodes('*') A(nd)
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT Prefix FROM AllNamespaces ns WHERE ns.namespaceUri=A.nd.value('namespace-uri(.)','nvarchar(max)')) ns
)
SELECT XPath
      ,NodeValue
      ,NestLevel
      ,ElementPosition
      ,SortString
FROM recCte
--WHERE NodeValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SortString;
```

--The result
/*

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| XPath                                                                                                                                                      | NodeValue                | NestLevel | ElementPosition | SortString                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderDate[1]                                                                                      | 2020-03-16T10:30:56.000Z | 4         | 1               | 00001000010000100001                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:customerServiceIdentifier[1]                                     | ETHA15302121             | 6         | 1               | 000010000100001000020000100001           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:instanceCharacteristic[1]/ns4:action[1]/ns4:code[1]              | Modify                   | 8         | 1               | 0000100001000010000200001000020000100001 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:instanceCharacteristic[1]/ns4:instanceIdentifier[1]/ns4:value[1] | OS014-AHEFV5T9           | 8         | 1               | 0000100001000010000200001000020000200001 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderVersion[1]                                                                                   | 1                        | 4         | 3               | 00001000010000100003                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiAction[1]                                                                                                      | Create                   | 3         | 2               | 000010000100002                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| /root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiVersion[1]                                                                                                     | 1                        | 3         | 3               | 000010000100003                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
```

*/

--just to show, that the created XPath is working as expected:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('dummy1' AS ns1,'dummy2' AS ns2,'dummy3' AS ns3,'dummy4' AS ns4,'dummy5' AS ns5)
SELECT @xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderDate[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:customerServiceIdentifier[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:instanceCharacteristic[1]/ns4:action[1]/ns4:code[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderItem[1]/ns3:instance[1]/ns4:instanceCharacteristic[1]/ns4:instanceIdentifier[1]/ns4:value[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiFocus[1]/ns2:orderVersion[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiAction[1]','nvarchar(max)')
      ,@xml.value('/root[1]/ns1:manageWorkItemRequest[1]/ns1:wiVersion[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The idea in short:

- The namespace prefixes can be defined by your own. The underlying URI is important.
- The first cte will create a set of all occuring URIs and return this together with a prefix.
- The recursive CTE will traverse deeper and deeper into the XML. This will continue as long as `APPLY` with `.nodes()` can return nested nodes.
- The full name is concatenated as well as the full XPath.
- The CASTs and COLLATEs help to avoid data type mismatch (recursive CTEs are very picky with this).
- The concatenated SortString is needed to ensure the same order in your output.

### UPDATE: You might think about `FROM OPENXML`

Just to mention it: There is the absolutely outdated `FROM OPENXML`, which is - afaik - the only way to get literally everything back:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root xmlns="default" xmlns:ns="dummy">
  <a ns:test="blah">blub</a>
  <ns:b test2="hugo">blubber</ns:b>
</root>';

DECLARE @DocHandle INT;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @xml;
SELECT * FROm OPENXML(@DocHandle,'/*');
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle;
```

the result

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| id | parentid | nodetype | localname | prefix | namespaceuri | datatype | prev | text    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 0  | NULL     | 1        | root      | NULL   | default      | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 2  | 0        | 2        | xmlns     | xmlns  | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 10 | 2        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | default |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 3  | 0        | 2        | ns        | xmlns  | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 11 | 3        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | dummy   |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 4  | 0        | 1        | a         | NULL   | default      | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 5  | 4        | 2        | test      | ns     | dummy        | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 12 | 5        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | blah    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 6  | 4        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | blub    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 7  | 0        | 1        | b         | ns     | dummy        | NULL     | 4    | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 8  | 7        | 2        | test2     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | NULL    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 13 | 8        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | hugo    |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
| 9  | 7        | 3        | #text     | NULL   | NULL         | NULL     | NULL | blubber |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+--------+--------------+----------+------+---------+
```

As you can see, this result contains namespaces, prefixes and content. But it is very clumsy and far away from "today" :-)

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side! Pure magic of the `OPENXML()` based solution. Sometimes even a 'dead horse' is still kicking. 

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I'm pretty sure, that this `FROM OPENXML` is running through the XML with simple string methods, top-down. Together with `OPTION EXPLICIT` we can speak of the *walking dead* :-)